# d3: repeat transition for series of elements?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having trouble getting a transition to repeat, for a series of elements, in this case a set of three lines.  The animation runs just fine once, but when it is repeated (with the same data), all three lines merge into a single line (the last array in `data`).  What am I doing wrong?

```js
(function() {
    var w = 100, h = 100
    var div = d3.select('#sketches').append('div')
    var svg = div.append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)

    var x = 0, y = 55

    var data = [
        [x, y, x+20, y-40],
        [x+10, y, x+30, y-40],
        [x+20, y, x+40, y-40]
    ];

    (function lines() {
            svg.selectAll('line')
                .data(data).enter().append('line')
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr('x1', function(d) {return d[0]})
                .attr('y1', function(d) {return d[1]})
                .attr('x2', function(d) {return d[2]})
                .attr('y2', function(d) {return d[3]})
                .transition()
                .duration(3000)
                .ease('linear')
                .attr('x1', function(d) {return d[0] + 60})
                .attr('y1', function(d) {return d[1]})
                .attr('x2', function(d) {return d[2] + 60})
                .attr('y2', function(d) {return d[3]})
                .each('end', function(d) {
                    d3.select(this).remove()
                    lines()
                })
    })()
})()
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}
svg {
  background-color: silver;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="sketches"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `each` function will initiate for each line you have. So actually what you are doing is calling `lines()` three times every time. Why it's yieling the output of one line I'm not entirely sure (still looking into it) but for some reason, it seems like `data` defaults to the last array so its only setting the drawing to be based on `data[3]`.

To fix it, you want to make sure `lines()` only gets called after it has finished going through removing all the lines so it only runs once. I'm pretty sure there is better way (i.e. a promise of some kind so after all of `each` has ran, it'll run a function, but what you can do is set a `count` and then just run `lines()` every N times where N is the number of lines you want removed. Because you go through array `data` and append a line for each index, N is `data.length`.

(I'm gonna see if there's a cleaner way to do this and I'll edit my answer if I find a way but hopefully this helps you understand the issue at the very least)

```js
(function() {
    var w = 100, h = 100
    var div = d3.select('#sketches').append('div')
    var svg = div.append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)

    var x = 0, y = 55

    var data = [
        [x, y, x+20, y-40],
        [x+10, y, x+30, y-40],
        [x+20, y, x+40, y-40]
    ];
    
    var count = 0;
    (function lines() {
            svg.selectAll('line')
                .data(data).enter().append('line')
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr('x1', function(d) {return d[0]})
                .attr('y1', function(d) {return d[1]})
                .attr('x2', function(d) {return d[2]})
                .attr('y2', function(d) {return d[3]})
                .transition()
                .duration(3000)
                .ease('linear')
                .attr('x1', function(d) {return d[0] + 60})
                .attr('y1', function(d) {return d[1]})
                .attr('x2', function(d) {return d[2] + 60})
                .attr('y2', function(d) {return d[3]})
                .each('end', function(d) {
                    d3.select(this).remove()
                    count++;
                    if (count == data.length) {
                      count = 0;
                      lines();
                    }
                })
    })()
})()
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}
svg {
  background-color: silver;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="sketches"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves it, and now the `each()` call problem seems obvious.  Also, since you've given me the right terms to Google, I see at least one other user corroborates your method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23119420/652626

Comment: @niteshade yeah after looking into it more, I found this is the practice that Mike Bostock recommends. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20773846/1168661)